# Call API in Collection Widget

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

i would like to create collection widget[like Gmail] for my app. i am the new to this. To show the Widget info,  I will call the API using retrofit and get the json details. Using the response i have to set it widget. To implement this, I have below doubt -  Where i have to CAll API. Onupdate / Adaptor class

Comment: in your activity/fragment call api in `onCreate()` , on api success response add widget and set response data.

Comment: If tap manual refresh, how we will get it..

Comment: on manual refresh click call it again api.

Comment: If i call the APi in AppWidgetProvider onupdate method, Its not getting update. if you have any sample, it will help us...

Comment: @R karthik have look [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/update-widget-in-onreceive-method.html) hope it will help you.